# Rails Rspec, Pass model data created in spec file to controller tested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm rspec newbie. I have a question.

-- spec to test controller file

```rb
describe "POST #" do  
  it "test update holiday_type" do
    u = User.create(email: "myemail") #edited
    data = { 
      email: "myemail",
      holiday_type: 1,
    }   
    post :update_holiday, data
    expect(assigns(:status)).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

-- in controller file

```rb
def update_holiday
  @status = true
  u = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  return render json: {:status => @status = params[:email]} if u.nil?

  h = Holiday.create(user: u, holiday_type: params[:holiday_type])
  @status = h.valid?

  return render json: {:status => @status}
end
```

-- output for test

```rb
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:status)).to eq(true)  
   expected: true
        got: "myemail"
```

Why controller cannot use the user created at spec file ?

Environment of both is not test ?

User.all.size printed in controller is 0 despite of be created at spec file.

Comment: Are you sure that u = User.create("myemail") actually creates a user. Not sure if you have a validation for example valid email?

Comment: @MirzaMemic oh sorry, miss typing. actually code is `User.create(email: "myemail")`

Comment: Yeah but does it create a user? Have you checked? Type inside console and see if it returns true

Comment: @MirzaMemic omg!! it's my fault.. you are right. User has some validates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that in rspec the user created?

I think it should be something like this,

```
u = User.create!(email: "myemail")
```

by using `create!` it will give you error if the user not created